# Why site collection administrator required permissions on config db connect to site through Visual Studio?

Tags: 2016, visual-studio-2015

when I try to connect to a SharePoint site from Visual Studio 2015 I get an error in the Event Viewer.
The user who logged in to WFE server is site collection administrator of the site

Site is connected after I add the login user as db_owner to config database, here why site collection administrator required permissions on config db connect to site through Visual Studio?

[image: screenshot]

SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config_2016' on instance 'SQL2016' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

> Login failed for user 'domain\med'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, configuration database maintains list of farm solutions and their deployment status, so in order to deploy farm solution you need access to Configuration database, content database in addition to local admin access on server and farm admin access.